# In printme function it sets all falses to true

Tags: c++

I am creating a simple car creator game to practice things like inheritance and classes. And I am stumped by this. when I debug it says that the values are  what they should be but then it goes to the printme function and it sets them to true no matter what.

```
cout << "Does your car have stripes?" << endl;
bool validInput8; // stops from sending code all of the place and mixing cars
string inputStripes;
inputStripes = lower(inputStripes);
do
{
cin >> inputStripes;
    inputStripes = lower(inputStripes);

    if (inputStripes == "yes")
    {
        sportscar.Stripes = true;
        validInput8 = true;

    }
    else if (inputStripes == "no")
    {
        sportscar.Stripes = false;
        validInput8 = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your input is not valid. Please enter yes or no!" << endl;
        cin.get();
        validInput8 = false;
    }
} while (!validInput8);
Continue();
cin.get();
clear();
sportscar.PrintCarDetails();
```

and this is the Print Function

```
#include "SportsCar.h"

SportsCar::SportsCar()
{
    Spoilers = false;
    Stripes = false;
}
void SportsCar::PrintCarDetails()
{
    cout << "You have finished your car! You are " <<                                                                         
ColorTypeToString(Color) << " and have " << numdoors << " doors!" << endl;
        if (Spoilers = true)

{
    cout << "Your sports car has some super sweet spoilers and you look like a total baller" << endl;
}
else if (Spoilers = false)
{
    cout << "Your car doesnt have spoilers so you are boring" << endl;
}
if (Stripes = true)
{
    cout << "Your car has stripes and you will often be confused as a racecar" << endl;
}
else if (Stripes = false)
{
    cout << "You dont have stripes but your driving a sports car who can complain" << endl;
}

        }`
```

Comment: `==` is for comparison `=` is for assignment

Comment: And don't compare booleans against true or false, just do: `if(condition)` or, if you need negation, `if(!condition)`; additionally, you have `if(condition) else if (!condition)` - *if* reaching else, the complement **will** be true, so just drop the second if: `if(condition) {} else {}`

Comment: Im so dumb! I realized that like 2 hours later and was so frustrated with myself! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You are using one = on your IF statements and not two. With one you are just assigning the value and not checking if it is actually true.